# Graphics: Why floats for coordinates?

Tags: graphics, screen, coordinates

In many graphics libraries I've seen coordinates stored as `floats` or `doubles`. My question is, why should they not be stored as simple integers? What more precision can you get, the double is still going to have to be converted to an integer at some point (you can't blit an image on the screen starting from pixel 45.8, for example :P ).

Comment: Coordinates aren't converted to integers. Only very rarely will a game-space coordinate gave any sort of direct correlation to a pixel.

Comment: @David Lively I meant at the end of the computation, when everything is ready to be printed on the screen and not in the intermediary calculations (or is that what you also meant?). Is it possible to display something on the screen in non-integer coordinates (at a hardware level)?

Comment: Pixel coordinates ARE ultimately converted to ints, as they are used to calculate the pixel address in the display buffer. This is typically handled in hardware.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, you can blit an image from 45.8. It's more about the coordinate system, in which the graphics library utilises, and how they manage translation and transformation of graphics etc. Moving an image via, Vectors is a good example...

i.e. Polar Coordinates, or the Cartesian coordinate system in relation with a 2D coordinate systems...

An example, you want a ball graphic to randomly bounce around a windows form.  An intuitive way to accomplish this is:

- first, bounce back the canonical way
  (dx = -dx or dy = -dy depending on
  the collision)
- then convert the dx and dy to polar coordinates (theta and r)
- jitter theta by a small amount (+ or - a few degrees, according to your taste)
- make sure theta isn't heading into a wall that you just bounced off
- convert theta and r back to dx (x) and dy (y) coordinates (which are of an integer data type)...

Get the drift?

May find this [useful](http://www.fundza.com/rman_shaders/polar_coords/index.html).